# Magento 2 Permission Issues

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions

During development of a magento 2 site I keep getting permission issues. When I move from modes I get "`Cannot change permissions for path.`" Is there something else that I should be doing?

Comment: Yes, I do agree it is a bit of a pain. What user are you logged in as in the command line? Is this the magento file system owner (not www-data) and does this owner have full acess (read/write/execute)?

Comment: I am logged in as root

Comment: The M2 setup requires a specific user, not www-data, to be magento system owner. Running any bin/magento command as root will create files and folders as root, which may cause issues. See: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

We have a deployment in which we use 'su magento_user -s /bin/bash -c "bin/magento setup:upgrade"' to run the scripts as a specific user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The M2 setup requires a specific user, not www-data, to be magento system owner. Running any bin/magento command as root will create files and folders as root, which may cause issues. 
See: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

We have a deployment in which we use the following command for example

`su magento_user -s /bin/bash -c "bin/magento setup:upgrade"`

to run the scripts as a specific user